# Ruby string single quotes causing trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, bash, escaping

I am trying to create a cronjob using whenever gem.

```
every 1.day, :at => "12:00pm" do
    grep_part_of_command = '"@timestamp":"'+Date.today.to_s
    command "cat logstash_development.log | grep '#{grep_part_of_command}' > todays_logstash_development.log"
end
```

What I want to achieve:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cat logstash_development.log | grep '"@timestamp":"2016-04-20' > todays_logstash_development.log'
```

But when I open my crontab, what I get is :

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cat logstash_development.log | grep '\''"@timestamp":"2016-04-20'\'' > todays_logstash_development.log'
```

Note the extra `'\'` around the grep matcher string.

Can anyone help me find my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems correct! Whenever uses single quotes everywhere, so that special symbols like `!` are not interpreted in shell. `'\''` is a way of print single quote in a single quoted string. Try the following:

```
echo 'grep '\''"@timestamp":"2016-04-20'\'' > '
```

It will output:

```
grep '"@timestamp":"2016-04-20' >
```

So, don't worry! The output text is correct.

Comment: no actually the above command when I execute directly on terminal ends up showing a right angle on my terminal. You can try with some dummy file.

Comment: Imposibru! The ouput is [correct](http://s31.postimg.org/qu7pz7um3/echo.png). That's how bash interprets it. I've tried to explain in the first paragraph. Just in case, you are still in doubt research single quotes in bash programming or see this exactly the same [whenever issue](https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/327).

Comment: from above command I meant `cat logstash_development.log | grep '\''"@timestamp":"2016-04-20'\'' > todays_logstash_development.log`

Comment: As I said, `'\''` is a way to escape a single quote in a **single quoted string**. This means that the string must be quoted with `'`. Example: `echo 'logstash_development.log | grep '\''"@timestamp":"2016-04-20'\'' > todays_logstash_development.log'`. Here is a [result](http://s31.postimg.org/4yzth2xmj/echo.png). Also, don't use `cat`, use `echo`. `cat` expect a file, not a string.

Comment: Ok after a little exercise, what you said makes more sense now. Thanks a lot